# What is .crt and .key files and how to generate them?

Tags: ssl, java, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I've the following configuration:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/login.domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/login.domain.com.key
SSLCipherSuite ALL:-ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP
```

but I don't know how to generate `.crt` and `.key` files.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

[crt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) and key files represent both parts of a certificate, key being the private key to the certificate and crt being the signed certificate.

It's only one of the ways to generate certs, another way would be having both inside a pem file or another in a p12 container.

You have several ways to generate those files, if you want to self-sign the certificate you can just issue this commands

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > host.key
chmod 400 host.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -key host.key -out host.cert
```

Note that with self-signed certificates your browser will warn you that the certificate is not "trusted" because it hasn't been signed by a certification authority that is in the trust list of your browser.

From there onwards you can either generate your own chain of trust by making your CA or buy a certificate from a company like Verisign or Thawte.

Comment: after running "openssl genrsa 1024 > host.key" I got this in terminal: "e is 65537 (0x10001) " is it an error?

Comment: Yes, this means that openssl can't write the random seed to the default file it uses which is defined by openssl.cnf, by default in CentOS/RHEL this file is in /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf. Try executing the same commands as root in this case and see how it goes.

Comment: I try it as root, but I got "e is 65537 (0x10001)" again

Comment: Do you have SELinux activated on your machine? Check /var/log/messages to see why openssl can't write the file

Comment: I check /var/log/messages before and after run this command, nothing!

Comment: is there any other way to generate this key?

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/ is a free ssl provider. Take a look on it instead of paying a lot of money to those companies.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `"unable to load Private Key
4511002220:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.100.4/libressl-2.8/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:684:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY"` Is it because I don't have a PEM file but a KEY file?

Comment: My issue was I had a mal-formatted private key file. Not sure how it happened, but I used the file and tail commands on Linux to determine the issue.

Comment: can I expose the .crt file? Is that supposed to be public?

Comment: what is the difference between openssl -req and openssl req?

Answer (score 17):

These are the public (.crt) and private (.key) parts of an SSL certificate. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/104215/how-do-you-buy-an-ssl-certificate) for a plethora of relevant information, e.g. if you want to generate a cert yourself, or buy one.

Comment: Basic question but -- I'm assuming I ought to copy the .key file to my `~/.ssh` folder, when I upload my CSR file to my ssl provider?

Comment: @Qasim SSL-files don't have anything to do with SSH (which is what the .ssh-folder belongs to).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old post but I just did this:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout private_key.pem -out public_key.crt -days 365 -nodes -subj '/CN=issuer'
```