# How to set up TLS to work with a Postfix Mail Server

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, postfix, email-server, ssl-certificate

I have been tasked with implementing TLS on a Postfix email relay server for an international office.

I am aware that I need to modify '/etc/postfix/main.cf' to setup TLS.  We have another email relay server in the US that is setup with TLS and has the following TLS config:

```
# TLS parameters 'mail.company-name.com'
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/company-name.com.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/company-name.com.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_loglevel=5
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
```

I can implement this configuration on my international office's Postfix server, so I am just wondering if all I have left to do is generate a certificate for 'mail.company-name.in' similar to the certificate that is referenced in the following lines:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/company-name.com.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/company-name.com.key
```

The new configuration would be as follows:

```
# TLS parameters 'mail.company-name.in'
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/company-name.in.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/company-name.in.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_loglevel=5
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
```

Am I missing anything else that you may have noticed?  Any advice will be appreciated.

Please let me know if you have any questions and I will be happy to clarify.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do I just need to generate a CSR on the email relay server in question, and have an SSL certificate generated by a certificate-vendor that I then place in the appropriate directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you buy an SSL Certificate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/104215/how-do-you-buy-an-ssl-certificate)

Comment: Thank you for your response @JennyD. I guess I should have worded my question a little differently. I know how to generate a CSR and obtain a certificate from a CA. I guess I was more or less making sure that all I had left to do to enable TLS was to obtain a certificate for 'mail.company-name.in'. And that the above TLS configuration looked correct in /etc/postfix/main.cf. I appreciate the assistance.  Not sure why the downvote.

Comment: Edited the question to detail more precisely what I was asking.

Comment: @JennyD It's not about buying the certificate, it's about the configuration. But still not very clear.

Comment: If buying a cert is not feasible, then https://letsencrypt.org may be a temporary solution.

Comment: @peterh Getting the certificate is not the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume here that you do not already have a signed certificate for your domain, otherwise your question would be pointless.

If you want a certificate signed by a CA you need to go to a CA and give them your CSR, then you get a certificate. Which CA you chose is irrelevant, as long as your client's devices trust it.

To generate the CSR see you can use openssl:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out company-name.com.csr -keyout company-name.com.key
```

You need to answer a few questions, but except for the Common Name they are all irrelevant.

See also for example [How do you buy an SSL Certificate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/104215/how-do-you-buy-an-ssl-certificate) and a lot of other questions here.

---

EDIT:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/company-name.com.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/company-name.com.key
```

These lines define which certificate and key file to use for TLS sessions. If you want that clients can verify the validity, you need to provide the certificate chain with [smtpd_tls_CAfile](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_CAfile).

```
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer=yes
```

This enables opportunistic encryption. I.e. when a SMTP client connects, delivering a mail to your server / it delivers mail to another SMTP server, it announces that STARTTLS is available.

```
smtp_tls_loglevel=5
```

Useful for debugging. Note that the [docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_loglevel) do not recommend anything higher than 2 and 5 is not defined at all. `1` is reasonable.

```
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
```

Enables opportunistic encryption, but does not require it. You may want to set it to `encrypt` for submission.

```
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
```

Needed for session tickets and recommended.

You want to have a look at the BetterCrypto.org's guide [Applied Crypto Hardening](https://bettercrypto.org/static/applied-crypto-hardening.pdf), it contains a full example for Postfix.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess I should have worded my question a little differently. I know how to generate a CSR and obtain a certificate from a CA. I guess I was more or less making sure that all I had left to do to enable TLS was to obtain a certificate for 'mail.company-name.in'. And that the above TLS configuration looked correct in /etc/postfix/main.cf. I appreciate the assistance.  Not sure why the downvote.

Comment: Edited the question to detail more precisely what I was asking.  Thanks again for the above CSR command.

Comment: "And that the above TLS configuration looked correct in /etc/postfix/main.cf. I appreciate the assistance." I extended the answer on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response!  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Session cache database is NOT needed for sessions tickets. These are 2 different things (and tickets are preferred as they don't need any server-side storage). In recent versions of postfix, `smtpd_tls_session_cache_database` is not set by default.